# TransportWithMessageCredential and wcf 3.5 and hosted in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, security

Is TransportWithMessageCredential and wcf 3.5 and hosted in IIS supported?

I am using it with .net 4.0 and everythign seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I have used it, are you having issues back-porting to 3.5?

Comment: I just read somewhere where some guy said it was not possible.

Comment: All I can say, is that I have not had issues with `TransportWithMessageCredential` and .NET 3.5 SP1 on Windows Server 2008 R2.